# Removing my name from Indian immigration blacklist

Tags: visa-refusals, india, iraqi-citizens

Respect. I have came to India with student visa and i have overstay for 16 months after that i applied for Exit Visa in order to go back to my country (IRAQ) after 4 months of leaving India I applied foe student visa in the Embassy of India In Baghdad, Iraq, and they rejected my application. because my name is blacklisted in FRRO of India. so What is the process to remove my name from the Blacklist?

Comment: You have overstayed. Even if name is removed from blacklist, you'll probably be refused Indian visa for a long time

Comment: You overstayed for a whole sixteen months?

Comment: When did you overstayed? Last month? 5 years ago? 20 years ago?  It really depend on how long and how much circumstances changed.